# Textbox downsizes at printing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, printing, text

In QGIS 3.0 the print layout window shows the following:

[image]

The result after pdf exporting is this:

[image]

How can I prevent the downsizing?

Comment: Use labels instead of annotation. Using labels from `Layer properties -> Label`, you can control the size, the font, and other things.

Comment: We get data with annotations and have to work with them. They are also not connected to a layer. Is there a solution for the annotations or just your mentioned workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with annotation, then you can double click the annotation, select the text, and increase the font size until you are satisfied with result.

[image]

Layout View:

[image]

Output PDF:

[image]

Change the Font size of the annotation:

[image]

Layout View:

[image]

Output PDF:

[image]

**Update**

In QGIS 3.4 it works as explained in QGIS 2.18.

[image]

Layout View:

[image]

Output PDF (small font):

[image]

After increasing the font size:

[image]

Layout View:

[image]

Output PDF (big font):

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with the 3.0 version. Some colleagues with the 2.18 version do not encounter this problem

Comment: @Rubedo I updated my answer for QGIS 3.4. It is same as 2.18

Comment: Well the text box does seem to decrease in size in your examples as well. That's the problem. It's not about the text itself but the ratio in size of text box to the other objects. I don't want huge textboxes in QGis just to have medium sized one's on my plotted pdf's. It shoudl be the same size

Comment: @Rubedo This is the limitation of annotation, you are limited by the text box size. Another workaround is to create a point shapefile and add points roughly in the locations you want and attribute table you like. Then use labels as explained my comment to your question to control the font size including other options.